# Pandas Dataframe: New Column Reference Week Beginning Monday

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Wrote this function to reference and existing `date` column to create a new column called `wbm` (short for `week beginning monday`).

```
def wbmFunc(df, col):
    if df[col].weekday() == 0:
        return df[col]
    else:
        return df[col] + timedelta(days=(0 - df[col].weekday()))

df['wbm'] = wbmFunc(df, 'date')
```

Why does it return the below error?

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'weekday'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to construct a new column that takes the week begin Monday for a given date. I think to achieve this, even you fix the property bug, there is still some problem. Why not use the `pd.offsets` ? You can try the following code for the same purpose

```
def wbmFunc(df, col):
    w_mon = pd.offsets.Week(weekday=0)
    return df[col].apply(w_mon.rollback)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to access a datetime like property you have to use:

```
series.dt.weekday
```

Also note that since it is a property, you don't call a function on the series.

You can refer to the [pandas Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#datetimelike-properties) on this topic.